# wordpress add tags as p all time my code

Tags: wordpress, tags, shortcode

I use a slider called revoslider and use as other sliders shortcodes for show this elements

When I use the shortcode **without using the visual editor to insert** and save, the slider doesn't works because WordPress adds `<p>` tags into the javascript:

```
<p>         <script type="text/javascript"></p>
<p>             var tpj=jQuery;</p>
<p>                                 tpj.noConflict();</p>
<p>             var revapi1;</p>
<p>             tpj(document).ready(function() {</p>
<p>             if (tpj.fn.cssOriginal != undefined)
                    tpj.fn.css = tpj.fn.cssOriginal;</p>
<p>             if(tpj('#rev_slider_1_1').revolution == undefined)
                    revslider_showDoubleJqueryError('#rev_slider_1_1');
                else
                   revapi1 = tpj('#rev_slider_1_1').show().revolution(
                    {
                        delay:9000,
                        startwidth:960,
                        startheight:350,
                        hideThumbs:200,</p>
<p>                     thumbWidth:100,
                        thumbHeight:50,
                        thumbAmount:2,</p>
<p>                     navigationType:"bullet",
                        navigationArrows:"solo",
                        navigationStyle:"round",</p>
<p>                     touchenabled:"on",
                        onHoverStop:"on",</p>
<p>                     navigationHAlign:"center",
                        navigationVAlign:"bottom",
                        navigationHOffset:0,
                        navigationVOffset:20,</p>
<p>                     soloArrowLeftHalign:"left",
                        soloArrowLeftValign:"center",
                        soloArrowLeftHOffset:20,
                        soloArrowLeftVOffset:0,</p>
<p>                     soloArrowRightHalign:"right",
                        soloArrowRightValign:"center",
                        soloArrowRightHOffset:20,
                        soloArrowRightVOffset:0,</p>
<p>                     shadow:2,
                        fullWidth:"off",</p>
<p>                     stopLoop:"off",
                        stopAfterLoops:-1,
                        stopAtSlide:-1,</p>
<p>                     shuffle:"off",</p>
<p>                     hideSliderAtLimit:0,
                        hideCaptionAtLimit:0,
                        hideAllCaptionAtLilmit:0,
                        startWithSlide:0    
                    });</p>
<p>             }); //ready</p>
<p>         </script></p>
```

Because of this the code never works and I don't understand why WordPress adds these `<p>` for each line, it's ridiculous

I tried `add_filter` for content it still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm assuming all those `<p>` tags aren't actaully part of your code :)

Comment: No never , these tags as <p> insert wordpress when i put the shortcode , the slider system add jquery code and when shortcode show load jquery from the code and insert the tags i ftry add_filter to the class content but no works always insert these tags , regards

Comment: I edited your question, you have to wrap the tags in backticks (` <p> `) for them to show up outside of code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this topic on wp?

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/shortcode-is-being-surrounded-by-p-tags

seems to be a problem with nested shortcodes .. If it is your Issue at all?
Do you have a link to the slider you are using?

Comment: probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851886/p-text-added-to-html-text

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem once, and `add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop')` does not work on my theme. So what I did was the following:

1. In the **revo slider** admin area, select the slider that is not displaying well.
2. Look for the **troubleshooting** tab (Bottom right) then change the values
3. Jquery No Conflict Mode = ON
4. Put JS Includes To Body = FALSE
5. (**Important part**) Output Filters Protection = **By Compressing Output**

That way, the script will be just in one line therefore the auto paragraph filter will just add the p tag to a single line

Answer (score 1):

When editing a slider, in the **Troubleshooting** section, you've got an option called **Output Filters Protection**. Set it to **By Echo Output**, and revslider's shortcode function will bypass filters, including the faulty one that adds this `<p>` tags... It does that by outputting (echo) its content directly instead of returning it to wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried surrounding your code with `<div></div>` (without using any class or id)? It prevents Wordpress from surrounding text with `<p></p>` tags. I've used it to prevent `<p></p>` tags appearing around images, as described in [this topic](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/prevent-wordpress-from-wrapping-p-tags-around-images?replies=4) over at Wordpress.org.

Answer (score 1):

For those who might have had a similar issue, what worked for me was the following:

Since I concluded the issue was within my theme, I had spent some time looking for the issue and found the one line causing the issue:

```
  add_filter( 'the_content', 'do_shortcode', 7 );
```

I just commented it out and it sorted out the problem.