# Revolution slider creates p tag before

Tags: html, css, wordpress, revolution-slider

I've added a revolution slider to my Wordpress theme. There seems to be an issue where it creates a `<p>` tag before the slider which creates a white space, which does not look good.

When I look at the css and html code in the browser it looks like this:

Why does it and how can I remove the `<p>` tags before revolution slider?

```
<p><!-- START REVOLUTION SLIDER 4.6.0 fullwidth mode --></p>

<div id="rev_slider_3_1_wrapper" class="rev_slider_wrapper fullwidthbanner-container" style="margin: 0px auto; padding: 0px; max-height: 400px; height: 342px; overflow: visible; background-color: rgb(233, 233, 233);">
```

Comment: Short of fixing it via WordPress, you could hide that `<p>` element via CSS. Because it doesn't have a class or id, you'd need to target it via the preceding element—which we can't see without a link.

Comment: This question already exists [p-text-added-to-html-text][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851886/p-text-added-to-html-text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the Troubleshooting box of Revolution slider there is an option named `"Output Filters Protection"`. Enable it. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

It will be easier (most likely) to suppress the redundant `p`, seeing as it contains only a comment it is essentially empty. As such, you can target and hide it with:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/azc3xhkp/1/)

```
p:empty{
    display:none;
}
```

[More on `:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)

> The `:empty` pseudo-class represents **any element that has no children** at
>   all. Only element nodes and text (including whitespace) are
>   considered. **Comments** or processing instructions do not affect whether
>   an element is considered empty or not.

Comment: @ralph.m - comments are classified as empty content: http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/azc3xhkp/

Comment: it did not work only if i did this: p{
    display:none;
} but then it it also deleted all other <p> tags which contained text

Comment: That is strange! i can see that it works in the fiddle, but it does only work when i remove the :empty, but then again it removes all p tags then.

Comment: @PeterPik - jsfiddle had added erroneous whitespace- without this is works: http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/azc3xhkp/1/